# Magento 2.4.2: How to add Yotpo reviews carousel code in specific category pages?

Tags: php, frontend, magento2.4, html, owl-carousel

We've been able to display Yotpo reviews carousel on the homepage of our Magento store. But I need to display that also on a few specific category pages. I'm not sure where to add the following code so that carousel will display only in specific category pages.

```
<style>
.yotpo-reviews-carousel {max-width:1300px !important;position:relative !important;margin-left:auto !important;margin-right:auto !important;margin-top:-15px !important}
</style>


<div class="yotpo yotpo-reviews-carousel" data-header-customisation-enabled="1" data-header-customisation-color="#0000AA" data-header-customisation-font-size="18" data-header-customisation-text="Our customers speak...." data-header-customisation-alignment="left" data-background-color="transparent" data-mode="top_rated" data-type="both" data-count="15" data-show-bottomline="1" data-autoplay-enabled="1" data-autoplay-speed="3000" data-show-navigation="1">&nbsp;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that :

```
<?php 
$currentcategoryId = take from registry;
if(CURRENT_CAGEOGRY_ID == Need To Show) { ?>
<style>
.yotpo-reviews-carousel {max-width:1300px !important;position:relative !important;margin-left:auto !important;margin-right:auto !important;margin-top:-15px !important}
</style>


<div class="yotpo yotpo-reviews-carousel" data-header-customisation-enabled="1" data-header-customisation-color="#0000AA" data-header-customisation-font-size="18" data-header-customisation-text="Our customers speak...." data-header-customisation-alignment="left" data-background-color="transparent" data-mode="top_rated" data-type="both" data-count="15" data-show-bottomline="1" data-autoplay-enabled="1" data-autoplay-speed="3000" data-show-navigation="1">&nbsp;</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Dhiren. Please tell me what is take from registry;? I mean how to get it from registry?

Comment: Are you put above code in which file?

Comment: Specific category pages are where I need to show the carousel.

Comment: I am asking currently where you put the above code? and It will show for all category pages.